# Hadoop Security

Tags: hadoop, kerberos, hadoop-plugins, kerberos-delegation, mit-kerberos

[image: Scenario : - User logs on to his computer gets authenticated by Kerberos Authentication and submits a map reduce job]

I am trying to learn " How Kerberos can be implemented in Hadoop ?"
I have gone through this doc  https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HADOOP-4487
I have also gone through Basic Kerberos stuff ( https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KD2Q-2ToloE)

After learning from these resources I have come to a conclusion which I am representing through a diagram.
Scenario : - User logs on to his computer gets authenticated by Kerberos Authentication and  submits a map reduce job 
(Please read the description of the  diagram it hardly needs 5 minutes of your time)
I would like to explain the  diagram and ask questions related with few steps **(in bold)**
Numbers in yellow background represents the entire flow (Numbers 1 to 19)
DT (with red background ) represents Delegation Token
BAT (with green Background) represents Block Access Token
JT (with Brown Background) represents Job Token

Steps 1,2,3 and 4 represents :-
Request for a TGT (Ticket Granting Ticket)
Request for a service Ticket for Name Node.
**Question1) Where should be KDC located ? Can it be on the machine where my name node or job tracker is present ?**

Steps 5,6,7,8 and 9  represents :-
Show service ticket to name node , get an Acknowledgement .
Name Node will issue a Delegation Token (red)
User will tell about the Token renewer (In this case it is Job Tracker)

**Question2) User submits thisDelegation Token along with the job to Job Tracker. Will Delegation Token be shared with Task tracker ?**

Steps 10,11,12,13 and 14 represents:-
Ask a service ticket for Job tracker , get the service ticket from KDC
Show this ticket to Job Tracker and get an ACK from JobTracker
Submit Job + Delegation Token to JobTracker.

Steps 15,16 and 17 represents:-
Generate Block Access Token and spread across all Data Nodes.
Send blockID and Block Access Token to Job Tracker and Job Tracker will pass it on to TaskTracker

**Question 3)Who will ask for the BlockAccessToken and Block ID from the Name Node ?
JobTracker or TaskTracker**

Sorry, I missed number 18 by mistake.
Step19 represents:-
Job tracker generates Job Token (brown) and passes it to the TaskTrackers.

**Question4)Can I conclude that there will be one Delegation Token per user which will be distributed throughout the cluster and
there will be one Job token per job  ? So a user will have only one Delegation Token and many Job Tokens(equal to the number of Jobs submitted by him) .**

**Please tell me if I missed something or I was wrong at some point in my explanation.**

Comment: Rohit! Good Analysis; Did you got any solution to secure Hadoop? If yes, can you share the answer in this post?

Comment: Please Update answer if you got it @Rohit Sarewar

Answer (score 0):

Steps to follow to make sure Hadoop is secure

1. Install Kerberos in any server accessible to all cluster nodes.
   yum install krb5-server
   yum install krb5-workstation
   yum install krb5-libs
2. Modify Configuration file in KDC server configuration to setup acl files, admin keytab files, for the host.
   /var/kerberos/krb5kdc/kdc.conf
3. Modify Configuration file /etc/krb5.conf to setup kdc host and admin server
4. Creating database in KDC host

   $ kdb5_util create –r  host_name  -s
5. Add administrators to the ACL file

   1. vi /etc/kdamin.acl
   2. Add admin principal ‘admin/admin@host_name’ in that file
6. Add Admin principal 
   $addprinc admin/admin@host_name

Install Kerberos clients on all Cluster Nodes

yum install krb5-workstation

Copy krb5.conf to all cluster nodes

Make sure to enable Secure mode in Hadoop by setting required configurations
https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/SecureMode.html

Verify :

- Login as normal user to cluster gateway or node where user keytabs are deployed
- Run “kinit –k –t /location/of/keytab file username@host_name”
- And run HDFS commands or mapreduce jobs to verify cluster is secured

These are the basic steps to make sure kerberos is enabled in your cluster.

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop security mostly used Kerberos for authentication, sentry for authorization.
Ranger like gateways, knox is used for security aspects 
http://commandstech.com/latest-hadoop-admin-interview-questions/